# WindowsError: Error 2 The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: windows, python-3.x, windowserror

I'm learning Python (with Python 3.2) and have been following a few manuals.  In one, I was asked to change my current directory to one that contains a particular file I was asked to make and place there. I've been encountering the following error:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.getcwd()
'C:\\Users\\the mine comp'
>>> os.chdir("../Desktop")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#24>", line 1, in <module>
    os.chdir("../Desktop")
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified: '../Desktop'
```

I have tried these:

```
os.chdir("/Desktop")
os.chdir("\Desktop")
os.chdir(r"/Desktop")
os.chdir(r"\Desktop")
os.chdir("../Desktop")
os.chdir("..\Desktop")
os.chdir(r"../Desktop")
os.chdir(r"..\Desktop")
```

The only related information I found before resorting to asking here was utilizing raw strings for Windows path variables (sadly this is all happening on a Vista netbook), and normalizing the pathname with **normpath(path)**.  I have tried the former as displayed above (am I using it right?), and I don't fully understand how to utilize the latter, or if it is even applicable to my problem.

The only other bit I've come across is that I may be invoking an escape character using backslashes in strings, but the raw string syntax ought to have taken care of that issue, right?  Also, I should note that the directory I am aiming to get to is this:

```
 C:\users\the mine comp\Desktop
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, I meant that _your_ last edit gave me the information necessary to write an answer. I should be more precise. (Not that it matters much.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/` or `\` forms are for changing to an *absolute* path. You have to know the entire path from start to finish for it to succeed.

The `..` forms are for *changing up a directory*. You only need them if you're moving upwards or "sideways".

Try just `os.chdir("Desktop")`. You're already in the `C:\users\the mine comp\` directory, so you don't need to move up or move to an absolute location. (Consider, if you wanted to open a file in the directory -- you just name the file. Same thing for subdirectories.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience, time, and knowledge. I understand - and realize how silly it all was for me not to see!